# Can't Update Mutable Field in Struct?

Tags: struct, f#, mutable

Can anyone tell me why this Counter struct won't work?  It always resets the value to 0 between calls to Incr.

```
type Counter = 
    struct

        val mutable i: int 

        member public this.Incr() =
            this.i <- this.i + 1

        member public this.Count = 
            this.i
    end

let noCounty(s:string): int = 
    let x = new Counter()
    x.Incr()
    x.Incr()
    x.Count
```

Comment: Don't do this. :-) I mean do not mutate inside structs. You can if you want to by explicitly making making x `mutable`.

Comment: I made the counter int mutable?  This is a simplified code snippet showing my problem.  I need to do this for performance reasons.  I'm updating fields as I iterate over millions of 3D points.  I don't want to box ints and floats into ref types.

Comment: Yes, of course. `struct` is a value type and is passed by value, hence you need make the value that holds the struct itself mutable, because when you mutate the counter you also mutate the whole struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of mutable structs is always confusing, because there are situations where the struct is unexpectedly copied when you use it in certain ways - so it is a good idea to avoid mutation inside structs.

You can make this work by marking the `x` variable inside `noCounty` mutable. Given your current definition of `Counter`, the following works as expected:

```
let noCounty() = 
    let mutable x = new Counter()
    x.Incr()
    x.Incr()
    x.Count
```

I agree this is pretty confusing. I think the logic is that if you define the variable as immutable, then the compiler copies the value of the struct into a new variable before making any call that might mutate it. As a result, the compiled code looks more like:

```
let noCounty () = 
    let x = new Counter()
    (let t1 = x in t1.Incr())
    (let t2 = x in t2.Incr())
    (let t3 = x in t3.Count)
```

I would expect the compiler to give me some warning about this - so perhaps the lack of warning in this case should be reported as a compiler bug. (Though the behaviour is probably intended.)

Comment: I thought I was doing something wrong, but ILSpy confirmed this.  If it sees any mutable member (even internal), it silently clones the variable.  I may have to abort using F#.  I'll be using commercial libraries written in c# and can't have method calls triggering a silent duplication of large 3D meshes.

Comment: @EricP If you mark the variable as mutable, then there is no silent duplication. Also, if you have large 3D meshes, then they are presumably stored in an array (or something like that), so they'll be heap allocated anyway (and even if the struct that stores the reference was duplicated, the mesh itself would not...).

Comment: If you set the warning level to 5 or activate warnon 52 the compiler will warn you about defensive copying.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Thank you.  F# being immutable is now less mysterious.  I was worried that arrays were immutable, but no reference types are.  I changed the Counter definition to a class and the caller did not have to specify mutable for it to work.  This raises the question of why all the talk about immutability and thread safety benefits of F#.  .NET defaults that params are passed by val.  I'm seeing it as a pointless set of local rules for val types and an interesting OO pattern of read-only, linked objects everywhere else.

Comment: @EricP That's a topic for much longer explanation :-). There are two concepts - immutable objects and immutable variables. Immutable objects are much more important than immutable variables.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why it does not work the way you have it, but it works this way:

```
type Counter() = 
    [<DefaultValue>]
    val mutable i: int

    member public this.Incr() =
        this.i <- this.i + 1

    member public this.Count = 
        this.i
```

Comment: This is slightly different though, this is a `class` not a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you can:

```
[<Struct>]
type Counter = 
        val mutable i: int 

        member public this.Incr() =
            this.i <- this.i + 1

        member public this.Count = 
            this.i

let  mutable x = Counter() // You need to make the struct itself mutable
x.Incr()
x.Incr()
x.Count
//val it : int = 2
```

To be honest, the compiler should complain about this behavior. While it's not a good idea to mutate in general, and in structs specifically; you can, but you need to make the `x` itself mutable, because you are changing the struct itself, which is a value type. The other answer gives you a class, which is a reference type.